# Document design with multiple embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have a Schema question regarding MongoDB. I have a User table with 6 different related entities.

```
public class Profile
{
    public List<Entity1> {get;set;}
    public List<Entity2> {get;set;}
    public List<Entity3> {get;set;}
    public List<Entity4> {get;set;}
    public List<Entity5> {get;set;}
    public List<Entity6> {get;set;}
}
```

When i show the profile page, i have to show all the data related to the profile. After reading MongoDB tutorials, my initial design was to embedd all the six documents inside Profile document. But i am concerned that, it may exceed the document size. So currently i have 6 seperate collections, and each collection entity has a ProfileId(Indexed) in it. On Profile view, i make 6 different database calls based on ProfileId and show all the results.

```
public class Entity1
{
  public int ProfileId {get;set;}
  ......
  ........
}
```

Is this acceptable ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [mongo 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/), the maximum document size is 16MB which is quite a lot without any BLOBs or something. So if you always want to retrieve the entire profile embedding all the lists is definitely your first choice.

Without knowing your use case, I typically experience apps built on top of mongo becoming slow due to too many queries, in particular if you're working with a remote database. Remember that mongo does not support joins, so accessing 7 collections really means 7 round-trips!

Hence, I would start with the embedded solution and do a bit of document size measuring from time to time in order to check the size. If 16MB is really not enough, you will probably have a single entity list growing too large - in that case, I would only extract this single list to its own collection.

If you want to have maximum flexibility like being able to switch easily while you are evaluating your document sizes, you could additionally store your data to the 6 other entity collections as you are doing now, but without ever reading them. If you have to switch later on, you simply change the corresponding queries and delete the embedded fields from the Profile collection.

Comment: Thank you ! I really liked your idea of having individual collections as well. I have a sidebar showing on profile page, for example show people with similiar skills. Can i query the individual collections for that purpose ?

Comment: I may have to probably ask this as a seperate question, i have a 2 GB VPS where i am planning to install MongoDB as well as my website, is this good enough to begin with ?

Comment: @user636525 sure you can query the individual collections! But with suitable indexed, you could probably get pretty much the same performance with the embedded solution. The nice thing about mongo is that it is actually meant to be tailored to your individual needs. If you want to store de-normalized data or pre-aggregations of any kind, just do it as long as there is a clear rationale for it.

Comment: your second comment would indeed be a seperate question, personally I'm not very experienced with the minimum hardware requirements for running a mongod instance - all I can say is that I never got into much trouble on my development machine (which has 16GB)...

Comment: Thanks i will try to find out if anybody has any experience in deploying MongoDB on a windows VPS environment.